# How to see which formulas reference a given cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to see which cells reference a given cell in their formulas, in Google Sheets?

For example, if cell C1 contains `=SUM(A1:A5)`, and cell D1 contains `=SUM(A5:A8)`, I'd like to somehow be able to determine that cell A5 is used in two places: C1 and D1, without prior knowledge that A5 is referenced by C1 and D1. It would be similar to how clicking on a formula highlights which cells it references, but the reverse.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## Short answer

Use find & replace

## Explanation

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the Advanced Find and Replace dialog
2. Write A5 on the Find field
3. Turn on the **Also check within formulas** option. This will turn on the View All formulas spreadsheet option.
4. Click the Find button

[image]

## Tips

Use `\$?A\$?5` and check **Search using regular expressions** to find all the different reference forms (A5, A$5, $A5, $A$5) with a single search.

Comment: Adding to this, use `Cmd+Shift+H` on a Mac to open the dialog. Alternatively, go to the `Edit` menu and click on `Find and Replace`.

Comment: I'd also suggest looking for version with dollar signs: $A5 and $A$5

Comment: @MegaMatt Thanks. I added a related tip.

Comment: Anyone know how to search only within same tab/sheet?

Comment: @cellepo In the Find and Replace dialog, click the Search dropdown and select This Sheet.

Comment: Any idea how to find formula linking to A6? The formula is A5:A8 so regular expression '$?A:$?5' will not find it.

Comment: I've suggest an edit. Until it is approved, it is that the regex appears to be wrong and should have been `\$?A\$?5`, but you may as well expand it to `^=.*\$?A\$?5` to only search for formulas.

Comment: @HeathRaftery Thanks for your reply, regular expression fixed.

Comment: Caveat: may not work if you are using things like VLOOKUP, MATCH, INDEX...

Comment: To exclude `A50`, the regex can be improved to `\$?A\$?5\D` (not a digit after 5). It's incredible GSheet still does not do this natively, when Excel has had this feature for years.

Comment: this does not find references via ranges (except when it is one of the start:end cells), let alone named ranges