# How to show all cells that are referenced across a number of cells

Tags: google-sheets

Here is a similar question: [How to see which formulas reference a given cell in Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/100791/how-to-see-which-formulas-reference-a-given-cell-in-google-sheets)

Unfortunately the accepted answer does not solve my problem. I am trying to categorize my income and expenses in Google Sheets. What I want is a way to click on each destination cell (where the total is calculated), and see all of the cells that are included in a SUM formula inside that destination cell. Crucially, I want to do this for multiple destination cells AT THE SAME TIME. This way I can quickly glance through and see if there are any missing cells i.e. transactions.

Alternatively, a way to permanently mark each cell that has been included in a destination cell formula would also suffice. So for example, if I have cells A5, A10, A16, A32 and they are referenced in a destination cell like this =SUM(A5, A10, ...) it would be helpful to mark those original cells in some way.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a minimal  example of source data and relevant formulas  in markdown format as well as an example of your desired result based on same.

Answer (score -1):

You may find useful [SUBTOTAL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649?hl=en) - between many useful functionalities, it allows you to perform some operations (SUM included) in different ranges, like this:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,B2:B4)  --> this in each of the subtotals in bold I put in the example, with the corresponding range
```

[image]

But then, when you use SUBTOTAL for the whole range, it will skip all the current SUBTOTALs, then omitting the duplications:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,B2:B13)
```

[image]